# Кнопки-ссылки в телеграм боте

Tags: telegram-bot

```
$keyboard = array(array("город-Пермь","[I](cities)","[[pagename|link text]]"));
    $resp = array("keyboard" => $keyboard,"resize_keyboard" => true,"one_time_keyboard" => true);
    $reply = json_encode($resp);
    $sendto ="https://api.telegram.org/bot".$this->params['BotInfo']['token']."/sendmessage?chat_id=".$chat_id."&text=".$message."&parse_mode =Markdown&reply_markup=".$reply;
```

Кнопки выдает только как сделать чтобы название кнопки было например Пермь а при нажатии выдавало /city3. Подскажите кто знает пожалуйста. Все варианты, в моем примере выдают текст только

Comment: Вам нужно, чтобы бот получал конкретные предопределённые команды, независимо от текста на кнопке?

Comment: Да.. чтобы на кнопке было Пермь.. а команда шла /city3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае стоит обратиться к [InlineKeyboardMarkup](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardmarkup). 
Вопрос [уже обсуждался](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38565275/4269118). Это не только позволит передавать боту нужные команды, но и позволит скрыть от пользователя текст передаваемых команд.